# Chaining API Requests with Retrofit + Rx

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to develop a client for Hacker News using [this](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) API, just for learning how Android works, as a personal project. I tried following some tutorials, but I am stuck at a certain point.

I want to retrieve the top N stories' titles, upvotes, etc. This would be done, using this api by:

1. Making a request to the api to retrieve the ID's of top posts (500 of them, to be exact)
2. For each ID, make a request to the api's posts endpoint to retrieve the details.

**It seems that I am stuck on how to create N different network requests for the posts that I want, retrieving them and putting them on a List, then displaying them on my Fragment.**
I am trying to follow an MVVM pattern, with Repositories. The relevant files are here:

NewsApi.kt:

```
interface NewsApi {

    @GET("topstories.json")
    fun getTopStories() : Single<List<Int>>

    @GET("item/{id}")
    fun getItem(@Path("id") id: String): Single<News>
}
```

MainRepository.kt (I):

```
interface MainRepository {

    fun getTopStoryIDs(): Single<List<Int>>

    fun getStory(storyId: Int): Single<News>

    fun getTop20Stories(): Single<List<News>>
}
```

The `News` object is a simple data class with all the JSON fields that are returned from `item/{id}`, so I am omitting it.

Here is my Repository, the implementation:

```
class DefaultMainRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: NewsApi
) : MainRepository {
    override fun getTopStoryIDs(): Single<List<Int>> {
        return api.getTopStories()
    }

    override fun getStory(storyId: Int): Single<News> {
        return api.getItem(storyId.toString())
    }

    override fun getTop20Stories(): Single<List<News>> {
        TODO("HOW?")
    }
}
```

The top questions I have are:

1. How can I make chained API calls in this way, using Retrofit / RxJava? I have reviewed previous answers using flatMap, but in my case, using a List of Int's, I do not actually know how to do that correctly.
2. Is this the right way to go about this? Should I just ditch the architectural choices I've made, and try to think in a wholly new way?
3. Say I can complete `getTop20Stories` (which, as the name implies, should retrieve 20 of the news, using the result from `getTopStoryIDs`, first 20 elements for the time should do the trick), how would I be able to retrieve data from it? Who should do the honors of retrieving the response? VM? Fragment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single** as a return type in your case will not be the best option because it is designed to only maintain single stream. **concatMap** or **flatMap** on Single will not either because it will try to map list of items to another list of items which is not the case
here.

Instead you could use **Observable** or map your Single to Observable by using **toObservable()** with **concatMapIterable** operator which maps your single item to sequence of items.

I used **concatMap** operator instead of **flatMap** because it maintains order of the list items so your data won't be mixed up.

```kotlin
getTopStoryIDs()
.map { it.take(20) }
.toObservable()
.concatMapIterable { it }
.concatMapSingle { singleId ->
    api.getItem(singleId)
}
.toList()
.subscribe { items ->
//do something with your items
}
```

This code will work but it's not the best solution because you will make 20 or more api calls which will hurt your network data and device battery so I wouldn't use it if it is not completely necessary.

If you have any questions fill free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

You where on the right track with FlatMap.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
getTopStoryIDs().flatMap { storyId -> getStory(storyId) }
```

Comment: This type of call would not work for me, because the type of `storyId` in your answer is `List<Int>`, as opposed to just a single `Int`.