# RxJava - how to wait to result of async tasks wihiting doOnNext

Tags: android, rx-java

How can I achieve that doOnNext wait to the results of multiple asynchronous tasks?

For example -

```
public void getImages(User user) {
    Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<User>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull FlowableEmitter<User> emitter) throws Throwable {
            emitter.onNext(user);
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(user -> {
                ArrayList<String> imagesUrls = user.getUrls();
                for (String url : imagesUrls) {
                    storage.getReference().child("images").child(url).getBytes(ParametersConventions.FIREBASE_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_MAX_SIZE).
                    addOnSuccessListener(bytes -> {
                       doSomething(bytes);    
                    });
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(user -> {
                doSomething();
            })
            .doOnComplete(...);
}
```

and I want that the doOnNext which calls to doSomething will be called after all the asynchronous calls to download the images are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn that API call into a reactive type and merge it into the main flow:

```java
int max = ParametersConventions.FIREBASE_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_MAX_SIZE;

public Completable downloadAsync(URL url) {
    return Completable.create(inner -> {
                           storage.getReference()
                           .child("images")
                           .child(url)
                           .getBytes(max)
                           .addOnSuccessListener(bytes -> {
                                doSomething(bytes);
                                inner.onComplete();
                           });
                     });
}
```

Together:

```java
Flowable.create(emitter-> {
       emitter.onNext(user);
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .concatMapSingle(user -> 
                 Flowable.fromIterable(user.getUrls())
                     .concatMapCompletable(url -> downloadAsync(url))
                     .andThen(Single.just(user))
             )
             .doOnNext(user -> {
                 doSomething();
             })
             .doOnComplete(...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is work. But maybe you have any idea if it is possible to run all the Completable in parallel?  It seems like it runs Completable after another so it is relatively slow.

Comment: `flatMapCompletable`.

Answer (score 0):

**doOnNext** operator is fired every time there is a new item on a stream so it is not the best option for you. Try using map/flatMap/concatMap operator depending on your needs. If you need to make several calls and then do something with the data you can look at similar question I've already answered link: [Chaining API Requests with Retrofit + Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69133290/chaining-api-requests-with-retrofit-rx/69138230#69138230)
in which you can find a way to make sequential network calls and then do whatever you want with a list of data :D

Comment: The problem I have is that the data I use for the async tasks is not the object that flows through the stream so I can't use maps' operators as much as I understand.
I need to find a way to block the async tasks or use callback somehow.

Comment: Mixing asyncTask with Rxjava is not the best practise. I recommend you to use just RxJava alone which will improve readability and testability of your code.